# How to write if condition in #ifdef. for Staging. in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, preprocessor-directive

I need to add one more condition inside this call **Staging**..

how to do it in this condition.

```
  #ifdef MYAPP_PRODUCTION
        buildMode = @"Production";
    #else

    #ifdef MYAPP_RELEASE
        buildMode = @"Release";
    #else MYAPP_DEBUG
       buildMode = @"Debug";
    #endif
    #endif
```

another is `MyApp_Staging` need to include in this if condition how to do this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You could do something like this to contain all the different options including the new Staging Mode and make the whole statement cleaner:

```
#ifdef MYAPP_PRODUCTION
    buildMode = @"Production";
#elif MYAPP_RELEASE
    buildMode = @"Release";
#elif MYAPP_DEBUG
    buildMode = @"Debug";
#elif MYAPP_STAGING
    buildMode = @"Staging";
#endif
```

Answer (score 64):

Your question is not very clear... If you want multiple conditions in a #ifdef, here is a solution:

```
#if defined(MYAPP_RELEASE) && defined(MyApp_Staging)
    // ...
#else
    // ...
#endif
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for, even if it wasn't what the OP was wanting

Comment: || works also :)#if defined RELASE || defined STAGING

Answer (score 14):

In Swift and Xcode 7, the syntax has changed:

```
#if DEBUG || RELEASE
    let URL = "https://www.example.com/beta"
#elseif APPSTORE
    let URL = "https://www.example.com/prod"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want to negate the condition with 2 build targets, use like this.

`#if !(TOWNTALK || EPISD)`

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
#if defined(MYAPP_PRODUCTION)
  buildMode = @"Production";
#elif defined(MYAPP_RELEASE)
  buildMode = @"Release";
#elif defined(MYAPP_DEBUG)
  buildMode = @"Debug";
//#elif defined(MYAPP_STAGING)
#else
  buildMode = @"Staging";  
#endif
```